# Imprimir dados de Base de Dados com FOR em Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

Eu sou iniciante na framework laravel, na qual tenho uma duvida, ao imprimir registos da base de dados para uma tabela html, em todos os exemplos que vi era usado o `foreach`, eu também tenho utilizado.

```
 @foreach($result as $data)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $data->id }}</td>
        <td>{{ $data->nome }}</td>
        <td>{{ $data->email }}</td>
        <td>{{ $data->telefone}} </td>
        <td>{{ $data->morada}} </td>
        <td class="text-center"><a href="{{ url('updateUtilizador/'.$data->id) }}" class="btn btn-primary">Editar</a> <a id="teste{{$data->id}}" href="{{ url('deleteUtilizador/'.$data->id) }}" class="btn btn-danger">Apagar</a> </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Mas eu nesta altura de "treino da framework" eu queria utilizar a estrutura `for` em vez do `foreach`, atualmente este e o código que tenho com o for, esta a ir buscar todos os dados bem, apenas não sei como faço para imprimir.

```
 @for ($i = 0; $i <= count($result); $i++)
<?php var_dump($resut); ?>
<tr>
    <td>{{ $result[$i][nome] }}</td>
    <td>{{ $data->nome }}</td>
    <td>{{ $data->email }}</td>
    <td>{{ $data->telefone}} </td>
    <td>{{ $data->morada}} </td>
    <td class="text-center"><a href="{{ url('updateUtilizador/'.$data->id) }}" class="btn btn-primary">Editar</a> <a id="teste{{$data->id}}" href="{{ 

url('deleteUtilizador/'.$data->id) }}" class="btn btn-danger">Apagar</a> </td>
    </tr>
@endfor
```

VAR_DUMP da variavel

```
array(2) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#287 (5) { ["id"]=> int(16) ["nome"]=> string(1) "e" ["email"]=> string(1) "e" ["telefone"]=> string(1) "e" ["morada"]=> string(1) "e" } [1]=> object(stdClass)#289 (5) { ["id"]=> int(19) ["nome"]=> string(2) "cc" ["email"]=> string(1) "c" ["telefone"]=> string(1) "c" ["morada"]=> string(1) "c" } } array(2) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#287 (5) { ["id"]=> int(16) ["nome"]=> string(1) "e" ["email"]=> string(1) "e" ["telefone"]=> string(1) "e" ["morada"]=> string(1) "e" } [1]=> object(stdClass)#289 (5) { ["id"]=> int(19) ["nome"]=> string(2) "cc" ["email"]=> string(1) "c" ["telefone"]=> string(1) "c" ["morada"]=> string(1) "c" } } array(2) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#287 (5) { ["id"]=> int(16) ["nome"]=> string(1) "e" ["email"]=> string(1) "e" ["telefone"]=> string(1) "e" ["morada"]=> string(1) "e" } [1]=> object(stdClass)#289 (5) { ["id"]=> int(19) ["nome"]=> string(2) "cc" ["email"]=> string(1) "c" ["telefone"]=> string(1) "c" ["morada"]=> string(1) "c" } }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para isso terá de alterar a função da sua querry .

```
 $cases = DB::select('select * from tabela');
 $array = json_decode(json_encode($cases), true);`
 return view('sua view', ['cases' => $array]);
```

na linha de codigo acima e o resultado da querry e atribuido na forma de array.

E para utlizar o array é como o Kayo Bruno indicou

```
   @for ($i = 0; $i < count($cases); $i++)
    <tr>
            <td>{{ $cases[$i]['id'] }}</td>
            <td>{{ $cases[$i]['nome'] }}</td>
            <td>{{ $cases[$i]['email'] }}</td>
            <td>{{ $cases[$i]['telefone'] }} </td>
            <td>{{ $cases[$i]['morada'] }} </td>
            <td class="text-center">
                <a href="{{ url('updateUtilizador/'.$cases[$i]['id']) }}" class="btn btn-primary">Editar</a>
                <a id="teste{{$cases[$i]['id']}}" href="{{ url('deleteUtilizador/'.$cases[$i]['id']) }}" class="btn btn-danger">Apagar</a>
            </td>                                              
    </tr>
@endfor
```

Answer (score 0):

Com o `for` você deve acessar a posição do item no `array` antes de acessar a propriedade.

```
@for ($i = 0; $i <= count($result); $i++)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $result[$i]->nome }}</td>
        <td>{{ $result[$i]->email }}</td>
        <td>{{ $result[$i]->telefone}} </td>
        <td>{{ $result[$i]->morada}} </td>
        <td class="text-center">
            <a href="{{ url("updateUtilizador/{$result[$i]->id}") }}" class="btn btn-primary">Editar</a> 
            <a id="teste{{$result[$i]->id}}" href="{{ url("deleteUtilizador/{$result[$i]->id}") }}" class="btn btn-danger">Apagar</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
@endfor
```

Comment: me deu este erro,Undefined offset: 2 (View: C:\Users\Ricardo\Desktop\Inventory-Management-System-in-Laravel\resources\views\admin\tabelaUsers\users.blade.php)

Comment: Amigo posta o `var_dump` do `$resut` por favor.

Comment: editei a pergunta

Comment: O problema aconteceu porque você tem um `array` de `array` de objetos.
Você tem 3 `arrays` onde cada um tem 2 `arrays` e em cada um você tem os dados do seu objeto.

Comment: e como eu posso resolver isso?

Comment: Uma solução seria você fazer outro laço antes desse.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103096/discussion-between-ricardo-faustino-and-kayo-bruno).

Comment: sera que pode explicar mais detalhadamente

Comment: array(2) { [0]=> array(5) { ["id"]=> int(16) ["nome"]=> string(1) "e" ["email"]=> string(1) "e" ["telefone"]=> string(1) "e" ["morada"]=> string(1) "e" } [1]=> array(5) { ["id"]=> int(19) ["nome"]=> string(2) "cc" ["email"]=> string(1) "c" ["telefone"]=> string(1) "c" ["morada"]=> string(1) "c" } } array(2) { [0]=> array(5) { ["id"]=> int(16) ["nome"]=> string(1) "e" ["email"]=> string(1) "e" ["telefone"]=> string(1) "e" ["morada"]=> string(1) "e" } [1]=> array(5) { ["id"]=> int(19) ["nome"]=> string(2) "cc" ["email"]=> string(1) "c" ["telefone"]=> string(1) "c" ["morada"]=> string(1) "c" } }